# How to connect MySql database to SqlDataSource object

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am using SqlDataSource object to connect with the ASP.Net chart control. And I am using the MySql Database. How to assign mysql db to SqlDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up an ODBC connection to you MySQL you might use something like ...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      ProviderName="System.Data.Odbc"
      DataSourceMode="DataReader"
      ConnectionString="dsn=myodbc3dsn;"
      SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, LastName, Title FROM Employees">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Hope that helps,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL Connector/Net`  is what you want.

An excerpt from the documentation

> Connector/Net lets you easily develop .NET applications that require secure, high-performance data connectivity with MySQL. It implements the required ADO.NET interfaces and integrates into ADO.NET-aware tools. Developers can build applications using their choice of .NET languages. Connector/Net is a fully managed ADO.NET driver written in 100% pure C#.

Download it from [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html)